# How to programmatically add a webpart to a page?

Tags: web-part, application-pages

I have created a webpart, now I need to add that webpart programmatically into the EditForm.aspx page. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a feature and on the activation of the feature you can add the webpart to the page.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        using(SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(page url, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            YourWebPart webpart = new YourWebPart();
            webpart.ZoneID = "Top";
            webpart.Title = "My Webpart";
            wpManager.AddWebPart(webpart,"Top" , 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Also have a look at [this link](http://www.keirgordon.com/post/Add-Web-Part-to-Page-Programmatically.aspx) for reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If suppose my webpart is not in the same solution, How will I be able to create an object and add it to a page? - Padmaraj.

Comment: DISPOSAL WARNING: You need to check the disposals here! OpenWeb() returns a SPWeb object that needs disposal. SPLimitedWebPartManager must be disposed properly as well.

Comment: I would like to add web part to default.aspx automaticlly exact when the web is created by using a feature. but I don't know when I must do it. because when feature is activated (within onet.xml) default.aspx doesn't exist

Comment: @Wictor Wilen MCA MCM MVP If you see a mistake in someone's post, you should fix the mistake.

Comment: It's not working on sandbox solution. It's showing error on "SPLimitedWebPartManager". Is it possible for sandbox solution ?

Comment: can this be done using the client side model?

Comment: Awesome post! It works, but I have some code in custom webpart in CreateChildControls, and I get "no definition for ZoneID". Tried convert MyWebpart to Webcontrols.Webparts.Webpart but no luck. strange that there is ZoneID in webpart scope. Can You give me advice? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63f59f4206bbdc83eda160af4490584a p.s.: altough I still can add webpart to page, but with no Title and ZoneID

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the SPLimitedWebPartManager.

Grab the SPFile object related to the EditForm.aspx page and then execute the [GetLimitedWebPartManager method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.getlimitedwebpartmanager.aspx) on the SPFile object. Use the limited web part manager to modify the web part page.

Answer (score 0):

This might take you a step further: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/How%20to%20create%20Web%20Part%20instances%20on%20pages%20using%20Features%20-%20FeatureReceiver%20-%20SPLimitedWebPartManager.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method of `SPLimitedWebPartManager` class which opens the closed web parts

```
    // Summary:
    //     Opens a dynamic Web Part that was previously closed by CloseWebPart so it
    //     renders on the WebPartPage.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   webPart:
    public void OpenWebPart(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart);
```

Comment: He wanted to add a webpart on a page, not open a close one!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to directly reference WebPart type in the code, you can use [SPLimitedWebPartManager.ImportWebPart](http://blog.degree.no/2011/01/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-import-and-use-web-parts-from-site-gallery/) method.

You just need to provide content of the *.dwp or *.webpart description file for the webpart instance you want to import.