# How to add a webpart to 2nd "Top" Zone of a Webpart Page Programmatically

Tags: web-part, development, page-layout, web-part-zone

I Have a webpart page, which has layout as shown in picture,

[image: WebPart Page Layout]

Now I want to add a webpart to second "Top" zone of my page but I dont know how to access it,
If I want to add it to first top zone I use this code,

```
WPMgr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
WebPart CmsWP = new WebPart();
this.WPMgr.AddWebPart(CmsWP, "Top", 0);
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi you can check this link it may help you


http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/how-to-programmatically-add-a-webpart-to-a-page

Comment: Hi, Nope this link didn't helped at all :| ?

Comment: You should not use the same name for different zones.

Comment: I am working on some big project made by someone, and there's many webparts and synchronized operations are happening, changing Name will simply gonna break numbers of other things :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your page has 2 zones with the same ID you're not going to stand much chance. Check what ID the second zone has, though - web part zones are controls and you can't have two web controls with the same ID.

Note that the text 'Top' is not necessarily the same as the ID. Look at the zone's definition through something like SharePoint Designer:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Left" ID="CenterLeftColumn"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

This would display the heading of 'Left', but you'd need to refer to the zone with 'CenterLeftColumn'

Comment: True, but can I add a webpart to a zone using its ID, not name as atm I think am using its name, if am not wrong. Cheers

Comment: At the moment, you're using 'Top' which is probably the ID of one web part zone, and the title of Two zones. You'd need to find out the ID of the second 'top' zone. The API documentation says that AddWebPart() uses the ID of the web part zone.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding webpart manually and saving it as a template, but just for knowledge if you can us how to find ID of a page please :)

Comment: If I get web part from my template page and add same web part into another page with the same zone Id my template has web part goes at the end of the page not the zone I want to add.