# My Site Blog Branding Error

Tags: my-site, branding

I am facing a very strange problem from the last few weeks . I applied feature stapling to our My Site so that when user tried to create his own personal site automatically our custom branding applies to his personal site and we achieved this functionality.

Then i observed that my feature is not getting applied when the user tries to create a blog in his personal site then after going through this post  [Sharepoint 2010 Mysite Blog branding (with publishing) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411225/sharepoint-2010-mysite-blog-branding-with-publishing-not-working/10438780#comment13758462_10438780) i was able to solve that problem also but now i am facing a new problem which is when we click on the heading of the blog document library its taking to empty page with URL /mysitetest/personal/testuser/Blog/Pages/default.aspx. I checked that when i change the link to /mysitetest/personal/testuser/Blog/default.aspx it  is working .Is there a way that i can achieve this for all the personal site collections . I am also attaching the image which will explain the problem more clearly [image: My Error]

Somebody please help me as i am completely out of options ...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Every web part has a TitleUrl property. I bet this is not set correctly in the blog template.
You will find how to add a web part to SharePoint programatically in an event receiver on another thread. [How to programmatically add a webpart to a page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/how-to-programmatically-add-a-webpart-to-a-page)

In your case you need to loop over all web parts returned by the [LimitedWebpartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.webparts) on the page, find the right one and set the [TitleUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.titleurl) to the correct propery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer stefan ,but when i removed the publishing feature the link is working fine . Does sharepoint not allows publishing features in Blogs

Comment: Blogs don't need the publishing feature and also the publishing infrastructure feature is not activated on the mysite. Good to know that you have found the problem.

Comment: Hi Stefan is there a way that i can copy the page from /mysitetest/personal/testuser/Blog/default.aspx. to  /mysitetest/personal/testuser/Blog/Pages/default.aspx. As i cannot disable the publishing in each personal site collection